# finding a point on a sigmoidal curve in r

Tags: r, regression, curve-fitting, non-linear-regression, sigmoid

Here is a data set:

```
df <- data.frame('y' = c(81,67,54,49,41,25), 'x' =c(-50,-30,-10,10,30,50))
```

So far, I know how to fit a sigmoidal curve and display it on screen:

```
plot(df$y ~ df$x)
fit <- nls(y ~ SSlogis(x, Asym, xmid, scal), data = df)
summary(fit)
lines(seq(-100, 100, length.out = 100),predict(fit, newdata = data.frame(x = seq(-100,100, length.out = 100))))
```

I now want to find a point on the sigmoidal curve when y = 50.  How do I do this?

Comment: *"I now want to find a point on the sigmoidal curve when y = 50"*. Perhaps I misunderstood, but isn't that exactly what the estimate for `xmid` gives? It's the value of `x` where the sigmoidal response is 50% of max.

Comment: I might be missing something, but  xmid = -38.10, and if I were visually estimate x value at y = 50 it appears to be around +5.

Comment: @MauritsEvers - good point. But, y = 50, is not the same thing as 50% of Asym.  Because the fitted value of Asym is likely not exactly 100.

Comment: @dww Ah I see. I had assumed the response to be normalised.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function that SSlogis is fitting is given in the help for the function as:

```
Asym/(1+exp((xmid-input)/scal))
```

For simplicity of notation, let's change `input` to `x` and we'll set this function equal to `y` (which is `fit` in your code):

```
y = Asym/(1+exp((xmid - x)/scal))
```

We need to invert this function to get `x` alone on the LHS so that we can calculate `x` from `y`. The algebra to do that is at the end of this answer.

First, let's plot your original fit:

```
plot(df$y ~ df$x, xlim=c(-100,100), ylim=c(0,120))
fit <- nls(y ~ SSlogis(x, Asym, xmid, scal), data = df)
lines(seq(-100, 100, length.out = 100),predict(fit, newdata = data.frame(x = seq(-100,100, length.out = 100))))
```

[image]

Now, we'll create a function to calculate the x value from the y value. Once again, see below for the algebra to generate this function.

```
# y is vector of y-values for which we want the x-values
# p is the vector of 3 parameters (coefficients) from the model fit
x.from.y = function(y, p) {
  -(log(p[1]/y - 1) * p[3] - p[2])
}

# Run the function
y.vec = c(25,50,75)
setNames(x.from.y(y.vec, coef(fit)), y.vec)
```

> ```
>         25         50         75 
>  61.115060   2.903734 -41.628799
> ```

```
# Add points to the plot to show we've calculated them correctly
points(x.from.y(y.vec, coef(fit)), y.vec, col="red", pch=16, cex=2)
```

[image]

Work through algebra to get `x` alone on the left side. Note that in the code below p[1]=Asym, p[2]=xmid, and p[3]=scal (the three parameters calculated by `SSlogis`).

```
# Function fit by SSlogis
y = p[1] / (1 + exp((p[2] - x)/p[3]))

1 + exp((p[2] - x)/p[3]) = p[1]/y

exp((p[2] - x)/p[3]) = p[1]/y - 1

log(exp((p[2] - x)/p[3])) = log(p[1]/y - 1)

(p[2] - x)/p[3] = log(p[1]/y - 1)

x = -(log(p[1]/y - 1) * p[3] - p[2])
```

Comment: Works perfectly - wonderful explanation as well.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: Upvoted for the excellence and clarity of the answer.